# Why Pipe symbol is missing in the help of tasklist?

Tags: windows

When i typed tasklist /? the pipe symbol is missing. After searching in internet i could find a way to search for a task list via

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119078/filtered-tasklist-piped-into-find-doesnt-show-console-output

Why the pipe symbol or findstr and other useful examples are not listed in help ??

What are the default examples which works for all commands??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pipe and `find` / `findstr` are not part of `tasklist`. 
`find` and `findstr` are separate programs,
and piping is a functionality provided by the command line interpreter (CLI),
a.k.a. the Command Prompt (`cmd`).